# afdjusting rows and columns in html

Tags: html

I am trying to obtain this InputBox:

[image: vbscript InputBox]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/FAX/BMDT/GYN8W455/FAXBMDTGYN8W455.MEDIUM.jpg))</sub>

with this html code

```
<body style="background-color:#EEEEEE" onkeypress='vbs:Default_Buttons' align='top'>
<table width='90%' height='100%' align='center' border='0'>
    <tr border='0'>
        <td align="left" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 11px;">
            Un Message
        </td>
        <td align='right'>
            <table  align='right'>
                <tr align='right'>
                    <input type="button" value="OK" name="btn_OK" onClick="vbs: Run_ProgramOK" style="font-size: 11px;"> 
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="btn_Cancel" onClick="vbs: Run_ProgramCancel" style="font-size: 11px;"><br><br>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width='90%' height='100%' align='center' border='0'>
    <tr>
        <td align='left' style="font-family: arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">
            <input type="text" size="60" id="txt_input"
            name="txt_input" style="font-size: 11px;" value="Un Input" ><BR>
            <!-- <input type="password" -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

but I can't get things right, the buttons are not left aligned.
I do not handle the table rows and column correctly

Comment: Using tables as layouts is bad practise and non-semantic.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/3nj1Lt2a/

Comment: So ? if no tables, what should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this:

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Staehren/9u50m4j0/)!

Should look more like the thing you are looking for, let me know if you wanted something else basically just aligned it to the left instead and gave it margin/right/top to position it exactly where it should be - not responsive, can be added.

Let me know what you think

```
<body style="background-color:#EEEEEE" onkeypress='vbs:Default_Buttons' align='top'>
<table width='90%' height='100%' align='center' border='0'>
    <tr border='0'>
        <td align="left" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 11px;">
            Un Message
        </td>
        <td align='left' style="margin-top: 5em;">
            <table  align='left' style="margin-right: 7.2em;">
                <tr align='left' "margin-top: 5em;">
                    <input type="button" value="OK" name="btn_OK" onClick="vbs: Run_ProgramOK" style="font-size: 11px; width: 5em; margin-top: 4em;"><br>
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="btn_Cancel" onClick="vbs: Run_ProgramCancel" style="font-size: 11px; width: 5em;"><br><br>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width='90%' height='100%' align='center' border='0'>
    <tr>
        <td align='left' style="font-family: arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">
            <input type="text" size="60" id="txt_input"
            name="txt_input" style="font-size: 11px;" value="Un Input" ><BR>
            <!-- <input type="password" -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

But like the guy who replied to you first said, tables are redudant, use div

Comment: that's nice ! is there a way to have the length of the input bar adjusted to the right side of the buttons ?  also. when I paste this in my small html window, there is no padding bellow the inputbar.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean? do you want the input bar on the right side of the buttons ? if that's the case then you should move it  above the other elements in the html and simple float it right then adjust accordingly with margin / padding.

Comment: This was just to give you an idea of how to format it - so you can tailor it the way you want it

Comment: If I answered your question please give me +1 :)